# Удалить все контейнеры

Tags: docker

Пытаюсь пересобрать все контейнеры. Для этого удаляю контейнеры, образы, тома. Запускаю команду **docker-compose build --no-cache**. На после сборки в контейнере базы данных уже существует старая база. Подскажите пожалуйста, как полностью удалить все контейнеры и все данные в этих контейнерах?

Comment: а вы уверены, что у вас БД монтируется не из папки на хосте (где файлы остаются)?

Comment: docker system prune --all   

docker volume prune    

docker-compose up

Comment: @Exploding Kitten, если я Вас правильно понял, нет. База первый раз импортировалась из локальной директории

Answer (score 1):

При удалении контейнера удаляются и все данные из него, а именно тот самый слой, который доступен для изменения в момент запуска контейнера.

Удалить можете просто  в bash вызвать `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)`